# RubyOnRails form.collection_select with data from second table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, collection-select

I am trying to use form.collection_select in an order form with data from a second model named products. I would like to use the field "product_reference" from the products table as selector in my HTML page.
When in the order form, I want to present all product_references to the user in a selctor, let the user make his choice, take this product_reference, and store the corresponding product_id in the order form (and database table field).
I have two tables, connected by id as in this schema:

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "order_date"
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_orders_on_product_id"
  end
```

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "brand"
    t.string "product_reference"
    t.string "description"
    ...
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["product_reference"], name: "index_products_on_product_reference", unique: true
  end
```

with the relationships described this way:

```
app/models/order.rb
  class Order < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
  end
```

```
app/models/ product.rb
  class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders
  end
```

I used the rails console, and got exactly what I want this way:

```
Product.all.map(&:product_reference)
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
=>
["C-Beau33",
 "C-Beau50",
 ...
 "B-Volk33",
 "B-Volk66"]
```

In my controller I have tried to assign @prodrefs with this dezired result, which I could then use in the collection_select:
Order Controller:

```
  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @prodrefs = Product.all.map(&:product_reference)
  end
```

I used this in my html view:
app/views/orders/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form.collection_select :order_id, Product.all, :id, @prodrefs, :prompt => 'Select Ref' %>
```

and step on this error message:

```
["C-Beau33", "C-Beau50", ... "B-Volk33", "B-Volk66"] is not a symbol nor a string
```

I think this error msg is not precisely linked to my problem, when trying just to add ".to_s" I only get another error on

```
undefined method `#<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fa1087ddda8>' for #<Product id: 1, brand: "Beaufort", product_reference: "C-Beau33",...>
```

What has been done so far:

in an older approach with a foreign key directly on this "product_reference", I was able to use this code in my view, worked like a charm, user could select the product_reference from the pull down menu in his browser:

```
<%= form.collection_select :fk_prodref, Product.order(:product_reference), :product_reference, :product_reference, :prompt => 'Select Ref' %>
```

This fk_approach has now been rejected, cause some extensions were necessary, with new model associations.

Looking at the RubyOnRails Guide, I can find the example on cities, and the explanation in ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder page, I see the description as:

```
collection_select(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So I believe my text_method is the problem here. When I translate from the guide, I come to this logic:

```
 collection_slct    html in city example
 method         ->  <option value=>
 collection     ->  Berlin
 value_method   ->  <select ... id="city_id">
 text_method    ->  <select name="city_id">
```

which let's me believe, that I want to have the 2nd row (collection) as all my product references. But I ammissing the point on the text_method then, cause the error message directs me there. Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  Kind of a mish-mash of several ways that can work, but you're close.

You can do this in a controller if you choose, though it would just be

```
@products = Product.all.order(:id). # or whatever order you would like
```

Then in your form

```
<%= form.collection_select( :product_id, @products, :id, :product_reference, prompt: 'Select Ref') %>
```

- The first argument is the attribute you are saving, in your case,
  where you have order_id above, it's really product_id.
- The section argument is the list of objects for the collection
- The third argument is the attribute from the collection you need to save to the product_id attribute.  In this case, it is `id`
- The fourth argument is the attribute name you would like displayed in the dropdown, `:product_reference`
- Lastly the fifth option is for the prompt

Comment: Gosh! so easy, really! I was thinking I had to use order_id, cause I am in order form partial, and saving an element in the order table. Looking at the Rails docu, it says the first field is "method", but the way you explained it makes it much more clear to me - thx so much!